# Subscriber is getting duplicate messages and publisher is publishing only once

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

I have Scenario where Subscriber is getting duplicate messages and publisher is publishing only once . how to debug this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: HI and welcome. It may help others answer if you show more details of what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this command with the *tibcoemsadmin64* CLI admin program:

*tcp://127.0.0.1:7222> show consumers topic=TOPIC_NAME*

*Id Conn User      T Topic        SASNMS Msgs Size   Uptime*

*3    4 anonymous T topic.sample +A----    0    0  0:02:07*

*5    6 anonymous T topic.sample +A----    0    0   25.451*

I am willing to bet that you will see more than one subscriber to the topic.

In the example above, I have two subscribers.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for you response. You mean to say there may be a chance of having two subscribers listened on the same TOPIC.If possible could you please elaborate it.

Comment: It is very possible and even typical to have many subscribers of the same topic. Topics are often used to implement pub/sub or fan-out patterns. In both cases, they are many destinations for the original message.